# How to prevent char repetition on name and surname with regex in C# model for validation field

Tags: c#, regex, model-view-controller

I'm trying to put a regular expression on my table model to validate name and surname in same form field, when:

1st Name must be at least 3 chars.

2nd Surname must be at least 2 chars.

3rd name can't be repetitives letters like aaaaa bbbb cccc.

So i tryed de code below with no success:

```
    [Display(Name = "Nome"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} letras e no máximo {1} letras.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]+(?!([a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]*?[a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]\3.*?))+ [a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]+(?!([a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]*?[a-zA-ZÁ-ú\b]\3.*?)))*$", ErrorMessage = "Não são permitidos caracteres especiais.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I could not avoid repetitions on the surname. :(

Comment: This is an interesting read for anyone trying to validate names... https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: There are a lot of interpretations for your question(s): 1) Should the name be of three words ONLY, or can there be just the 1st name and surname? 2) What do you mean by can't be repetitive letters? Does that mean that the WHOLE word should not be consisting of one letter, or there should be no consecutive similar letters in the name?

Comment: For questions like these, with conditions that are ambiguous, it would be really helpful for anyone who wishes to answer if you include some sample inputs and outputs you desire from them.

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd I’m tempted to suggest that you submit that essay as an answer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I decided I'd keep a reference to that post when I read the last line, "refer people to this post the next time they suggest a genius idea like a database table with a first_name and last_name column." Brilliant, and so relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `\w{3,} \w{2,} (?:(\w)(?!\1))+`

---

**Explanation**:

**\w{3,}** - Any word with a minimum width of 3 and max of unlimited

**Space**

**\w{2,}** - Any word with a minimum width of 2 and max of unlimited

**Space**

**(?:** - Start of the non-capturing group (Just for not appear on the results)

**(\w)** - A group capturing just a word

**(?!\1)** - The next word cannot be the same as the last one (Negative lookahead)

**)** - End of the non-capturing group

Hope it helps :)